# Export glTF: How to get separate metallic, roughness and occlusion textures?

Tags: materials, export, gltf, pbr

I have imported this [SciFiHelmet.gltf](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Sample-Models/tree/master/2.0/SciFiHelmet/glTF) file to Blender.

It comes with separate textures for occlusion and metallic/roughness (combined):

- SciFiHelmet_AmbientOcclusion.png
- SciFiHelmet_MetallicRoughness.png

In Blender it then looks like this:
[image]

When exporting the scene as *.gltf using Format "glTF Separate [...]",
Blender automatically merges the two textures into one texture with name:

- SciFiHelmet_AmbientOcclusion-SciFiHelmet_MetallicRoughness.png

**Is there a way to avoid this? I just want to export the original
and separated texture files, not a new merged texture.**

Help is very appreciated!

Comment: This might need to be filed as a request at https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO. I'm not sure whether merging ORM textures can be disabled at the moment. Using different resolutions for the two textures might prevent it, as a workaround.